# How to fix missing Bluethooth icon in settings in Windows 10?

Tags: bluetooth

I have checked in settings but I could not find Bluetooth

[image]

it's missing I need Bluetooth for a dynamic lock so plz help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOxOb.png)

Comment: Did you add / can you add a Bluetooth device?   Does Bluetooth show up in Device Manager ?  Generally (in my experience) Bluetooth is not needed for a Windows PIN, so you may wish to edit your question to say what kind of PIN.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add bluetooth devices, such as a mouse or security device, then the most common cause is that the device drivers are not installed. In most cases, when you install windows, using a lesser known motherboard, things like the chipset and bluetooth devices are not installed natively.

If you go to Device Management, you will see Unknown devices with a yellow exclaimation mark.

In order to solve the problem, you will need to download the correct drivers for your motherboard from the website and install them. Sometimes a reboot is needed to initiate the devices, but after that, bluetooth should work, and you should be able to connect your bluetooth devices.

Keep in mind, that most bluetooth devices have a certain pairing mechanism in place. You press a button for 2 seconds, a light starts flashing, and only then, will you be able to connect to that device. So, first initiate pairing mode on your device, then in the settings screen, press Add Bluetooth device, select the device once it is being found and that's it. Refer to the manual for your device on how to pair it.